# Writing Complex Numbers as a Vector in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, vectors, real-numbers

Generally speaking is it mathematically correct to write a complex number $z = x +  iy \in \mathbb{C}$, as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

$$z=\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{with } x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$

With row 1 being the $Re(z)$ and row 2 being $Im(z)$, i.e. 
$$Re: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto x \quad \text{and} \quad Im: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto y$$

Comment: Technically, a complex number $z$ is a member of $\mathbb C$ and not of $\mathbb R^2$, so that would not be "correct". But there probably may be reasons why would you want to use $\mathbb R^2$ instead, since they are quite similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the complex number space $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, the answer is yes. However, writing $(a+bi) \cdot (c+di)$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
c\\
d
\end{bmatrix}$$

does not make sense under normal vector multiplication - so you will need to define the multiplication operator in a different way.

**Another** way of doing this is to write complex numbers $a+bi$ as the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&-b\\
b&a
\end{bmatrix}$$

which has the advantage of normal matrix-matrix multiplication giving the same result as normal complex multiplication.

Comment: ,Okay I see, that way, we don't have to memorize 'Rules of Complex Arithmetic' as those 'Rules' come straight out of the laws of matrix multiplication and addition, when a Complex Number is written as a $2 \times 2$ matrix, correct?

Comment: @Perturbative Matrix-matrix addition, subtraction, multiplication and multiplication with inverse using these 2x2-matrices will give you equivalent answers as addition, subtraction, multiplication and division with corresponding complex numbers, yes. That said, the notation for complex numbers is generally a lot easier to use in applications.

Comment: I always find it funny when people praise the way using matrices to write complex numbers (in my experience often found in algebra). For the basic operations you need to know nothing about complex numbers except $i^2=-1$ whereas for the approach using matrices you first must define what a matrix is, how you add/multiply matrices, how you invert a matrix...

Comment: @Hirshy I hope I didn't come off as *praising* this method over "normal" complex numbers, I certainly don't. :)

Comment: @naslundx no, you didn't. It just reminded of a conversation I had last week with a friend of mine (who in fact is mainly interested in algebra) and we were talking about good ways to introduce complex numbers. And of course he praised the matrix way and was not willing to see, that while it is a good and interesting approach that can give you some insight into complex numbers, it can be rather difficult for new students to understand and begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the space $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to the $\mathbb R^2$ with respect to the corresponding maps (addition, multiplication etc.).

It works like this: Consider the bijection

$$ \pi: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R^2, x+iy \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we define a fitting addition and multiplication on the $\mathbb R^2$. As addition we just take the entrywise addition, i.e.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
y_1
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
x_2\\
y_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 + x_2\\
y_1 + y_1
\end{bmatrix}$$
And we define a fitting multiplication, i.e.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
y_1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x_2\\
y_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 x_2 - y_1y_2\\
x_1y_2 + x_2y_1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we can easily show that $\pi$ is a field isomorphism (left as exercise). Finally we can even define $Re$ and $Im$ like the following

$$Re: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto x \quad \text{and} \quad Im: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto y$$

This makes use of the fact, that $\mathbb C$ is a two dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space (a base is for example $(1, i)$).

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: How is the multiplication of two vectors defined?

Comment: @AlphaGo Here you go :)